# Definition of coercive function

Tags: calculus, optimization

I was studying coercive functions and I came upon three definitions:
$$f: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$M \in \mathbb{R}, r \in \mathbb{R}$$
1 - it's the usual, the one I saw most.
$$\lim_{||x||\to+\infty} f(x) = +\infty$$

2 - For all $M>0$, exist an $r>0$ such that $f(x)>M$ when $||x||> r$.

3 - Someone said it to me, so I dont know if its correct. it's like the second one, but without the constraint on M. Like...
For all $M \in \mathbb{R}$, exist an $r>0$ such that $f(x)>M$ when $||x||> r$.

I'm doing an exercise right now, and I want to use the third one, because I have an M, but I don't really know that M>0. But if the third one still holds true, I can use without fear.

I basically want to know: is those three equivalent, or just one and two(like stated in the answers already? M needs to be like M>0, or could be just any $M \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Are $M$ and $r$ part of the definition (i.e. does that define something like an $(M, r)$-coercive function)? Because as it stands I read it as "for all $M, r > 0$ [...]" and then the class of functions it defines is obviously empty.

Comment: Similarly, what's $M$ in the third definition? You write "without the constraint" but there is no constraint in 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would call your definition 1. coercivity.

For definitions 2. and 3. it looks like you have written them wrong. Note that if 2. read for every $M>0$ there exists an $r>0$ such that $f(x) \geq M$ for all $\|x\| \geq r$ then this would coincide with 1.

The word coercive can refer to the use of force to achieve a particular outcome, in a mathematical context you might see such a function subtracted from a differential equation to prevent blow-up to infinity. I think the term is frequently used in the optimisation community.

p.s dont worry about $M\in R \subset \mathbb{R}$, since if  that property holds for each $M>0$ it will hold for each $M \in R$.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2. and 3. statement is not the right definition. May be the 2. should say: To every M>0 there exists an r>0 such that f(r)>m  but this would be just the same as 1.

Answer (score 0):

Definition 1 is standard. Definitions 2 and 3 don't really define anything as you state them (the set described by definition 2 is empty and definition 3 contains a free variable $M$), but an equivalent definition to 1 close "in spirit" to 2 would be something like "for all $M > 0$ there exists an $r > 0$ such that $f(x) > M$ when $\lVert x\rVert > r$." Proving that this is in fact equivalent to 1 is a good exercise in the definition of $\lim$.